# im getting error code 127 while creating jenkins pipeline here is the script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines

```
pg_dump -h 10.12.0.4 -U pet--rsmb--prod-l1--usr -w -c -f 2022-08-10t1228z-data.sql
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BACKUP-RSMB--POSTGRESQL@tmp/durable-510acc0f/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BACKUP-RSMB--POSTGRESQL@tmp/durable-510acc0f/script.sh: pg_dump: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly indicates that the Shell executor cannot find `pg_dump` command. Either you have not set `pg_dump` properly in the Jenkins server or you have not added `pg_dump` to the executable $PATH.